# Is CPython interpreter itself and the script running in the same thread?

Tags: python

Is CPython interpreter itself (compiled binary code) and the python script running in the same thread?

Comment: Not necessarily, since the interpreter can actually release the GIL and use native threads for a lot of tasks. But when it hasn't released the GIL, I believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You may verify this yourself easily by running a script and using [`ps`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ps1.html) while it executes.

It might help if you just think of **Python** as the program, and a .py file as the **input** to that program.

The interpreter, interpreting your script, *is* the program.  The "Python script" is just a text file, and it doesn't make much sense to think of that script as some kind of process in the absence of an interpreter.